# How can I connect to Android phone with ADB over TCP without using a USB cable at all?

Tags: android, debugging, tcp, wifi, adb

Since my android phone does not connect via usb to my pc anymore (it just start charging), i would like to know if it is possible to install/debug apps (using Android Studio or Eclipse) via wifi (my device is NOT ROOTED). I have another phone (LGP690) that is configured to be a wifi hotspot. My PC and the other smartphone (an LG P880, the one with usb connection problem) are connected to it. Note that the LGP690 phone can be connected to my PC via usb.

Comment: Possibly duplicate question, go here : [how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: @Turrican Mmmm...my device is not rooted and i can't use a usb cable, otherwise that page is really useful (i already tried to debug via wireless and it worked, but only if you can initially connect the phone with a usb cable).

Comment: **"...it just start charging..."** : Are sure you haven't accidentally changed something in settings which defaults to 'charge only' when connected with USB or perhaps accidentally disabled 'USB debugging' option?

Comment: @MarcoMasci : Also, are you using a different USB cable than you have done previously? Some phone USB cables that come with chargers are 'power only' and don't have the data wires connected so can only be used for charging.

Comment: @Squonk. I have tried everything and i am thinking to proceed with a hard reset, but before that i would like to know if it is possible to start developing via wifi. When i connect it to pc via usb, my phone doesn't ask anymore which type of connection i want (charge only, MTP, thetering usb, software lg or PTP). Even if i select MTP from settings->connectivity->type of usb connection, the phone is not recognized by pc. The pc cable is always the same and it worked well unitl some days ago (i have tried another one, which is suitable for data transfer, but nothing happens).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing any of the options below with your LG P880?

- Connect your cellphone to your computer
- Right click on your `My Computer` and go to `Properties` then `Device Manager`
- Look for your device **(It may be under Other Devices or under a separate branch maybe LG)**
- When you find the device, right click on it and select uninstall
- In the meantime, you can go to this [link](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver) and download Universal Windows ADB Driver **(This one worked for me)** or if you want to use the one you downloaded from SDK Manager, just go to: `C:/Users/(Username)/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/usb_driver`
- When you finish uninstalling the driver unplug it and plug it back in so the computer can recognize the device.
- When the computer recognize it, go back into device manager and look for the device that has an yellow exclamation point.
- Right click on the device with the yellow exclamation point and click `Update Driver Software...`
- When the update driver window shows up, click `Browse my computer for driver software`
- **If you downloaded and installed the Universal ADB, the you must direct the path to** `C:/Program Files (x86)/ClockworkMod/Universal Adb Driver/usb_driver` **if not then to the other path which is the one I mentioned above**
- Wait until installation finish then restart the computer **(Optional)** then give it a try.

Comment: When i look at the device manager (4th point in your list), i can't found anything. Normally it would appear somthing, but it seems that the LGP880 does not trigger anything. I have installed usb driver from LG, the universal ADB driver, tried to off/on the phone, changed cable, changed usb port, tried everything. Maybe the usb port of the P880 is damaged, i don't know. This is the reason why i am searching an alternative way to used ADB over wifi without using a usb cable at all...

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a different PC and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Also, have you tried connecting your other phone (LG P690) and see if it connects with no problem?

Comment: Yes, the other phone connects without problems (i can install, debug etc...). No, i have not tried the P880 with another PC (i hope to do the test asap). The strange thing is that the P880 charges, so if the usb port of the phone is damaged, why it is able to charge???

Comment: It still charges but we still don't know if the usb port of the phone is damaged or if your PC is blocking it. Hopefully you can test in another PC so we can narrow the possibilities down.

Answer (score 0):

**Connect android phone without using USB cable except XIAOMI PHONES** 
==  MAKE SURE THAT YOUR PHONE HAS USB DEBUGGING ENABLED ==
== **IP Address** series should **NOT** be '0' like 192.168.**0**.10 
1. Connect your PC (Laptop) and Android phone to same wifi network. 
2. Goto Android SDK folder > platform-tools and Open command prompt holding Shift key from folder. 
3. Type command "adb tcpip 5555", and hit Enter, sometimes it gives error but ignore it and go ahead. 
4. Type "adb connect [YOUR PHONE IP]". example: adb connect 192.168.1.34 and hit enter, Your phone will be connected to PC.

Comment: why not xiomi phones ??